# How to pass parameter from ctk entry to the function in python

Tags: python, tkinter

So I wrote a small youtube audio downloader app, but I dont know how to pass the value that user inserts to the function.

I tested the app without the GUI, it works. So when I created GUI using custom tkinter(this is my first time using it) I get the following error: TypeError: Download() missing 1 required positional argument: 'link'
Here is the code

```
import customtkinter

from pytube import YouTube


customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

root = customtkinter.CTk()

root.geometry("500x350")


def Download(link):
    youtubeObject = YouTube(link)
    youtubeObject = youtubeObject.streams.get_audio_only()
    try:
        youtubeObject.download()
    except:
        print("Error!")
    print("Success!")


frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame.pack(pady = 20, padx = 60, fill="both", expand = True)


entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, placeholder_text= "URL")
entry.pack(pady=12, padx = 10)

button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, text="Download", command=Download)
button.pack(pady=12, padx = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify `Download` to get the value from the entry widget once it's called, rather than passing it in.

```
def Download():
    link = entry.get()
    ...
```